# How to generate high dimensional Sobol sequences for practical use?

Tags: monte-carlo, sobol-sequence

My goal is to be able to use Sobol sequences to do a large scale market simulation to reduce the variance and improve the accuracy of the results.
If I understand correctly, the use of Sobol sequences is very widespread in finance and Monte Carlo pricing.

However, what I don't understand is the low dimension in most implementations available. Max dimension 1111 seems to be common. This is, in practice, not even enough for pricing of a single, slightly more complicated, position like some barrier option on some basket of underlyings.

The problem is that the dimension is a hard limit, if your simulation requires a higher dimension than what is available you have to abandon the method and typically use standard Monte Carlo instead.

I know there are commercial libraries for generating high quality Sobol numbers for dimension of 100000 and beyond which should be sufficient.
Since Sobol numbers seems to be almost like a standard I wonder what the typical way to go here is. Do practitioners typically just use a third party library for this or do they make their own high quality high dimensional Sobol sequences?

Yes, I realize the answer of the above question highly depends on who the practitioner is and their skill level, but what I really want to know if it is reasonable to try to implement your own high quality, high dimensional Sobol sequences or if this is something that would take a group of skilled researchers several years to do?
If it is reasonable I would be happy to be pointed in the right direction with some references (I have a PhD in math and I am not afraid of digging into some hard work, as long as it is realistic and not takes years).

I am sorry if the question is a bit vague here, but I feel that this question is pretty common among people learning about Sobol sequences and their benefits. First one reads about Quasi random numbers and their nice properties, but then one is quickly taken down to earth again when the low dimension of all common implementations would not enable you to actually use them in a realistic setting except for some smaller proof of concept examples.

Comment: In most financial problems the risk factors are highly correlated, which means the "effective" number of dimensions is much lower than the nominal number. This is why the usual approach is to perform some type of dimension reduction before using QMC or a mix of QMC and standard MC. See for example this question and its answer [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/2528/482). Any problem which would depend crucially on such a large number of dimensions would be intractable anyway (my opinion only).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I will take a look at the linked example.